# Angular2 dynamic template modal is not opening

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I have implemented [Angular2-Dynamic-Templates](https://github.com/TylerDev6/Angular2-Dynamic-Templates/tree/master/src/app/templates/dynamic), every thing is same, but when i click on button to open a template on modal, template is created but can't open the modal, and no error is occurred.
The only change i have is:
I have to use `ngbModalContainer` on `template` tag of both `class-template.component.ts` and `custom-template.component.ts`, i think its missed on tutorial.
The main issue is modal is not opening.
bellow is my console:
[image]

Note: I'm using bootstrap4, i have changed css to force fade in/out.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment `ref.destroy();` on your template-service.ts